# Selecting a customer who have more then two address

Tags: database

I have two tables one is 'CUSTOMER' and another is 'ADDRESS' as follows

```
CUSTOMER(CID,FNAME,LNAME,AID)
ADDRESS(AID,ADDRESS,PHONE,EMAIL,CID)
```

A customer can have multiple address, I want to select all the customers with all addresses who have 'NAME LIKE' something

I want the result like

```
CID   FNAME       LNAME       ADDRESS      PHONE        EMAIL
1     someone1    something1  address1     9876543110   something@xxx.com
1     someone1    something1  address2     9876543110   something@xxx.com
2     someone2    something2  address1     9876543110   something@xxx.com
2     someone2    something2  address2     9876543110   something@xxx.com
```

Comment: Show us your code, which you need to improve or ask questions about.

Answer (score 3):

You can use %, it matches any string of zero or more characters.
For example

`SELECT Phone
FROM Person
WHERE Phone LIKE '415%';`

It will give all phone numbers starting with 415.

Comment: this does not answer the question.